# How to upgrade kmail

Tags: apt, upgrade, kde5, kmail

Here all version of my system :

```
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
Plasma Version 5.8.7
KDE Frameworks Version 5.36.0
QT version : 5.6.1
Kernel Version 4.4.0-83-generic
```

My kmail version is  5.2.3 and I can not get any search result in my mail folders.

I posted a bug tracking and the support told me I've to upgrade kmail as these kind of buggies had been fixed. My system seems to be up to date like a LTS version.
I installed the backports package listing as recommended is this page : 
https://community.kde.org/Plasma/Packages

What did I miss?

Thank

Answer (score 0):

I have Kmail 5.4.3 and get search results in my folders.  I upgraded from Kubuntu 16.04 to 17.04 and installed [KDE PIM 16.12.3 update](https://kubuntu.org/news/kde-pim-update-now-available-for-zesty-zapus-17-04/) which includes Kmail. I don't know if the update is compatible with Kubuntu 16.04

The backports package you installed is for Plasma (KDE's desktop environment) not Kmail.